# I can't open the sales order after changing the unit of measure of the associated product

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

These are the steps:

1. Create a sales order and a sales order detail with one product of
   the pricelist
2. After that change the uom of the product
3. Open the sales order

This is the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, 
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: 
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. 
Reference number for administrators or support: #E5A25827Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
 <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
<d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)</d2p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
</ErrorDetails>
<Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error.
<InnerFault>
<ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
<KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<d3p1:key>CallStack</d3p1:key>
<d3p1:value xmlns:d5p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d5p1:string">   
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveCommand.Execute()
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Guid auditingTransactionId, Boolean addRequiredColumns)
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Boolean addRequiredColumns)
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.InlineEdit.ReadFormDataBuilder.LazyLoadEntity()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.InlineEdit.ReadFormDataBuilder.WriteFormDataJson(TextWriter writer)
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.InlineEdit.ReadFormDataBuilder.WriteFormattedEntityData(TextWriter writer, Boolean isTurboForm)
at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Pages.Form.FormDataPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</d3p1:value>
</KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
</ErrorDetails>
</InnerFault>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I am not able to open any sales order with this product, the only way to fix this is changing back the uom or create a new sales order with the updated product.
This is Dynamics CRM 365 8.2 OnPremise.

What adittional configuration should I update after changing the uom of the product?